# What port should I use for TCP packet transfer

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

Hey  I will be sending data over Wi-Fi to my computer using Android and java, on my server side (Windows PC) I have this:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

And on the client side (Android):

```
InetAddress remoteAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
socket = new Socket(remoteAddr, port);
```

The question is what port would be recommended to use?

Comment: Any _non-reserved_ one, go big...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick any unreserved/unassigned TCP port number. Specifically, it is any number in the range 49152–65535.

The IANA page doesn't seem to be working at the moment, but here's a wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) with the same sort of information.

Comment: So something like 61809 (Used a random number generator to decide haha

Comment: I had the same problem, more of the reason I asked on here

Comment: Actually, ports `49152` up to `65535` are to be assigned by the operating system dynamically, aren't they? So you should probably use ports `1024` to `49151` instead, which are not reserved but will not be assigned dynamically, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use every port you want except the reserved that you can find [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml)

Comment: Its the IANA page, seems that is a little slow at the time.